# How to set up custom input dialog for saving data in Firebase when user clicks any textview widget in cardview?

Tags: java, android

In **MainActivity** I have `NavigationDrawer`. For each menu item, I have a fragment class with a corresponding layout. One of them is **MyCardFragment.java**. In this fragment, I am showing `CardView` through `RecyclerView`.

My `CardView` contains some `TextViews` and an `ImageView`. What I wanted is when a user clicks a widget it will open a custom input dialog (contains a `TextView`, an `EditText`, a positive button, and a negative button) for updating data in **Firebase Real-time database**. I created a dialog fragment class, but don't know how to implement it in my adapter class.

This is my main activity which holds `RecyclerView` and `CardView`:

MainActivity.java:

```java
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser != null){
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(currentUser.getUid());
            }

            mContext = MainActivity.this;

            mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_name);

            NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            //navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                            // set item as selected to persist highlight
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            // close drawer when item is tapped
                            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                            // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                            // For example, swap UI fragments here
                            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                                case R.id.nav_myCards:
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MY Cards");
                                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                                            .beginTransaction()
                                            .replace(R.id.content_frame,new MyCardFragment())
                                            .commit();
                                    break;

                            return true;
                        }
                    });

            mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(
                    new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                            // Respond when the drawer's position changes
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                            // Respond when the drawer is opened
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                            // Respond when the drawer is closed
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                            // Respond when the drawer motion state changes
                        }
                    }
            );

            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
            //Highlighted
            //onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));

            setupFirebaseAuth();
            if (currentUser != null){
                //updateNavHeader();
            }
        }
```

Custom Dialog Fragment:

DialogCompanyAddress.java:

```java
    public class DialogCompanyAddress extends DialogFragment {

        public DialogCompanyAddress() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_company_address,null));

            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //save data to the firebase
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Do
                }
            });

            return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

finally the adapter:

RecyclerviewAdapter.java:

```
    public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.MyHolder> {

        // ... constructor and member variables

        // Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
        Context mContext;
        List<Template> listdata;

        public RecyclerviewAdapter(Context context,List<Template> listdata) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.listdata = listdata;
        }

        @Override
        public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            /*// Inflate the custom layout
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);

            // Return a new holder instance
            MyHolder myHolder = new MyHolder(view);
            return myHolder;*/
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);

            return new MyHolder(view);
        }

        public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.pname.setText(listdata.get(position).getP_name());
    holder.pdesignation.setText(listdata.get(position).getP_designation());
    holder.pemail.setText(listdata.get(position).getP_email());
    holder.pphone.setText(listdata.get(position).getP_phone());
    holder.cname.setText(listdata.get(position).getC_name());
    holder.caddress.setText(listdata.get(position).getC_address());

    //holder.tempID.setText(listdata.get(position).getTempID());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(listdata.get(position).getC_logo()).into(holder.logo_image);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            //return listdata.size();
            int arr = 0;

            try{
                if(listdata.size()==0) {
                    arr = 0;
                } else {
                    arr=listdata.size();
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return arr;
        }

        class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            // Your holder should contain a member variable
            // for any view that will be set as you render a row
            TextView pname,caddress,pemail,pdesignation,pphone,cname,tempID;
            ImageView logo_image;

            // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
            // and does the view lookups to find each subview

            public MyHolder(final View itemView) {
                // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
                // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
                super(itemView);

                pname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_personName);
                caddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_address);
                pemail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
                pdesignation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_designation);
                pphone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_phone);
                cname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_companyName);
                logo_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                tempID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tempID);

                caddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext,"Clicked on Address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        DialogCompanyAddress address = new DialogCompanyAddress();
                        //address.show(getSupportFragmentManager);--->This line give me error

                    }
                });

        }
    }
```

Comment: did your dialog fragment pop up when click card item?

Comment: no sir i can't integrate my dialog fragment to my adapter class

Answer (score 1):

use a interface in your adapter like below

```
public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.MyHolder> {

public interface ClickListner {
    void IconClick(Template template);
}

Context mContext;
List<Template> listdata;


private final ClickListner listner;


public RecyclerviewAdapter(Context context, List<Template> listdata, ClickListner listner) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.listdata = listdata;
    this.listner = listner;
}

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

    return new MyHolder(view);
}


public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.pname.setText(listdata.get(position).getP_name());
    holder.pdesignation.setText(listdata.get(position).getP_designation());
    holder.pemail.setText(listdata.get(position).getP_email());
    holder.pphone.setText(listdata.get(position).getP_phone());
    holder.cname.setText(listdata.get(position).getC_name());
    holder.caddress.setText(listdata.get(position).getC_address());

    //holder.tempID.setText(listdata.get(position).getTempID());
Glide.with(mContext).load(listdata.get(position).getC_logo()).into(holder.logo_image);



    holder.bind(listdata.get(position), listner);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //return listdata.size();
    int arr = 0;

    try {
        if (listdata.size() == 0) {
            arr = 0;
        } else {
            arr = listdata.size();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arr;
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView pname, caddress, pemail, pdesignation, pphone, cname, tempID;
    ImageView logo_image;

    public MyHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        pname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_personName);
        caddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_address);
        pemail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        pdesignation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_designation);
        pphone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_phone);
        cname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_companyName);
        logo_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tempID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tempID);

    //            caddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //                @Override
    //                public void onClick(View v) {
    //                    //Toast.makeText(mContext,"Clicked on 
Address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    DialogCompanyAddress address = new DialogCompanyAddress();
//                    //address.show(getSupportFragmentManager);--->This line give me 
error
//
//                }
//            });

    }

    public void bind(final Template template, final ClickListner Listner) {
//            DeleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(View v) {
//                    delListner.onDeleteIconClick(card, position);
//                }
//            });

        caddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Listner.IconClick(template);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

and in your fragment you need to initialize the adapter. when initialize you can override the **ClickListner** interface.